# Displaying div onclick not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to display a slideshow like the one shown here:- (http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp) at the top when someone clicks "About Us, but I can't even get the onclick portion to work.

So far, I have:-

```js
document.querySelector("p").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector("div").style.display = "block";
});
```

```css
#here{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
  
<div id="here">Slideshow</div>
<p>About Us</p>
```

But it's not working for some reason. Can someone tell me what's wrong with the click function? I tried giving each of them individual IDs and I'm not sure what else to try. Thanks in advance for any help you guys can provide.

Comment: f12 will bring up developer console.. It will tell you the error..

Comment: for me it is working! however try replacing div with #here on javascript

`document.querySelector("#here").style.display = "block";});`

Comment: seems like the page was **not** completely loaded while the script got executed

Answer (score 3):

It should works, the **position** of your **script** is important make sure your script is defined after your **DOM**. Or you can add your script inside a `DOMContentLoaded`event.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //script here
});
```

```js
document.querySelector("p").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector("div").style.display = "block";
});
```

```css
#here{display: none;}
```

```html
<div id="here">Slideshow</div>
<p>About Us</p>
```